# addEventListener — How do I capture a value of another variable?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm new to JS. I need help on line 2...How do I go about getting the value of an independent variable when a button is clicked?
Basically  var i  is incremented every 100ms and I want to capture what its value is when a button is clicked.
Thanks plenty!

```
    function startGame(){
    **var clickValue = thebutton.addEventListener()** // I need this variable to capture to value of **i** when thebutton is clicked
    var i = -50
    var timer = setInterval(timerActual, 100);
    function timerActual(){
        console.log(i)
        i++;
        if (i===600) {
            clearInterval(timer)
        }
    }}
```

Comment: You have an `i` variable. Reference it?

Comment: `addEventListener` doesn't return anything. The listener function runs later when the event occurs. It doesn't make sense to return the value at the time you add the listener.

Comment: so you update a variable that both functions can reference and you read the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the variable in the event listener function.

```js
function startGame() {
  var i = -50
  let thebutton = document.querySelector("#button");
  thebutton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(`i = ${i}`);
  });
  var timer = setInterval(timerActual, 100);

  function timerActual() {
    i++;
    if (i === 600) {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector("#start").addEventListener("click", startGame);
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="button">See timer</button>
```